# Null is not an object (evaluating

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I want to add a class to an element with the id="key" but it doesn't work why ?? I am a beginners in js : this is the code :

```
audio.classList.add('yellow');
```

This is the error :

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(key).classList')
```

Comment: what is `key`? maybe you meant to write `document.getElementById('key')`

Comment: what is your definition of 'audio'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a sign the system does not find elements with id according to the value of the `key` variable.

**Example if the element does not exist:**

```js
document.getElementById("test").classList.add("blabla")
```

**Example element exists:** (*no error will be displayed in console*)

```js
document.getElementById("test").classList.add("blabla")
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the Id by string and not variable like so:
`document.getElementById('key')`